# Grails App to work as TCP/IP server too

Tags: grails, tcp

I would like my grails app (Restful Profile ) to open TPC/IP server connection (maybe port : 9000)
and wait for Client to connect (socket)

it might be wired but

We would like to combine TCP/IP server  + grails app

so

- device box can open connect (socket) to grails app via port 9000 and send/receive command from/to this grails app
- while grails app still can receive HTTPS request from another end point

Please advise

I'm not sure where I should put the TCP/IP server (groovy) portion to any part of grails-app

Comment: I've done this before using Spring Integration and the TCP/IP server within a Grails application. If you have a specific problem doing this then post that as a question, but general questions like this don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would like to code by groovy please give me some tutorial url

Comment: What happens if you open the TCP server from the Bootstrap init?